# Show that certain fractional linear transformations define rotations of the $2$-sphere via stereographic projection

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

I have the following exercise:

**Consider the standard stereographic projection $ S^2\setminus N \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^2$, with $N = (0, 0, 1), $
onto the plane $ z = 0 $. We can identify $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ and $ \mathbb{C} $ in the usual form $ (x, y)\Leftrightarrow x+iy $ and in this way we define the stereographic projection as a function $ \pi : S^2\setminus N \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $. Given $ a, b \in \mathbb{C} $ such that $ |a|^2+|b|^2 = 1 $, define a fractional linear transformation $ f : \mathbb{C}\cup \lbrace \infty\rbrace \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\cup \lbrace\infty\rbrace $ as $ f(z) = (az + b)/(-\overline{b}z + \overline{a}) $ where the bar means complex conjugation. Complete the definition of $ \pi $ with $ \pi(N) = \infty $. Prove that for any $ f $ as above, the map $ \pi^{-1}\circ f\circ\pi  $ is a rotation on the sphere.**

I know that the projection is:

\begin{align*}
\pi(x,y,t) &= \left(\frac{x}{1 - t}, \frac{y}{1 - t}\right),\\
\pi^{-1}(X,Y) &= \left( \frac{2 X}{1 + X^2 + Y^2},\frac{2 Y}{1 + X^2 + Y^2}, \frac{-1 + X^2 + Y^2}{1 + X^2 + Y^2}\right)
\end{align*}

and that the projection about the complex plane is
\begin{align*}
\pi(x,y,t)&=\frac{x+iy}{1-t} \\
\pi^{-1}(x+iy)&=\frac{(2x,2y,x^2+y^2-1)}{1+x^2+y^2}
\end{align*}

But trying to calculate every step, it seems to me almost imposible. So maybe there is a more theorical way to get the result?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The rotations of a sphere are precisely its oriented isometries of its usual (round) metric $g$, so if you have this fact available, one could just as well show that the f.l.t.s $f$ are all oriented isometries on $\Bbb C$, endowed with the pullback metric $(\pi^{-1})^* g$, which isn't too hard to compute explicitly. NB that when using this technique one must still address what happens at $\infty$.

Comment: I am not so familiar with that topics, so where can I read about the fact that the rotations of a sphere are precisely its oriented isometries of its usual (round) metric g?

Comment: Here's what looks like a sensible introduction: https://books.google.at/books?id=UlrmKjIjrzQC&pg=PA429&lpg=PA429&dq=oriented+isometry+of+sphere+rotation&source=bl&ots=ndKLrFU1dA&sig=stD1ADp2utKRgmW3kWOvAHAXErg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDEQ6AEwBGoVChMIo5KLnPHsyAIVx6oOCh2-TA_j#v=onepage&q=oriented%20isometry%20of%20sphere%20rotation&f=false